# How do I automatically open an external website in Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: javascript, ajax, https, xmlhttprequest, sencha-touch-2

I am communicating with a server and it sends me back a url to an external site.  How do I automatically open that url in a new tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simple `window.open` should to the trick.

```
window.open(url);
```

But I'm pretty sure Google knows it if you ask him nicely 'open new tab javascript'

Hope this helps